# Modifying height of inherited bootstrap style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a CSS newbie and I have to change some code where it looks like they are inheriting styles from bootstap..

```
 <style>
.thumbnail{display:table !important}
 </style>
 <div class="thumbnail">
```

So thumbnail is a cell inside a table and I need to change the height and weight of this cell, any suggestions on how I can do that? I am not seeing any height or width attributes for that style?

Thanks.

Comment: So add in your own style, have you tried that? `height: 200px;` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify bootstrap classes just add new class like this

**CSS**

```
.thumbnail-custom{
   background-color:red !important;
}
```

I think even !important is not needed

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail thumbnail-custom">
...
</div>
```

If you are using **LESS**

```
.thumbnail-custom{
  .thumbnail;
  background-color:red !important;
}
```

And **HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnail-custom">
    ...
</div>
```